# How to merge helm chart and vault agent tempate?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I have two helm chart templates.

```
{{- define "helpers.config.tpl" -}}
debug: "true"
db:
  app:
    dialect: "mysql"
    endpoint: {{`{{ with secret "` }}{{ default "common/data/mydata" $.Values.vaultSecretName  }}{{`" -}}{{ .Data.data.db }}{{- end }}`}}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "helpers.config" -}}
{{- $default := fromYaml ( include "helpers.config.tpl" . )   -}}
{{- $conf := .Values.configFile -}}
{{- toYaml (merge $conf $default ) }}
{{- end -}}
```

Also I have `values.yaml` like below.

```
configFile:
  db: 
    app:
      conn: 300
```

I want to add or modify attributes just passing values via `values.yaml` file. But I got error like `Error: 'error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 86: did not find expected key'` . How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Vault Agent Template](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/template) syntax includes an extra layer of templating, which gets produced by `helpers.config.tpl`.  If you invoke that template with empty `.Values` you will get out

```yaml
debug: "true"
db:
  app:
    dialect: "mysql"
    endpoint: {{ with secret "common/data/mydata" -}}{{ .Data.data.db }}{{- end }}
```

That's not valid YAML, though: YAML `{ ... }` should be dictionary syntax, not Go template syntax.  You have to force this string to be interpreted as a string.

Probably the most robust way is to use [YAML block scalar syntax](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793652), indenting the thing you're trying to emit but applying no other escaping:

```yaml
endpoint: |-
  {{`{{ with secret "` }}{{ default "common/data/mydata" $.Values.vaultSecretName  }}{{`" -}}{{ .Data.data.db }}{{- end }}`}}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me an advise! However the `db.endpoint` value seems `{{ with secret "common/data/mydata" -}}{{ .Data.data.db\n }}{{- end }}` after templiting. How do I remove new line inside of string?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DavidMaze
I solved this issue. It's kinda tricky, though. I formed my yaml document like below.

```
endpoint: |-
  {{`{{ with secret "`}}{{ default "common/data/mydata" $.Values.vaultSecretName }}{{`" -}}
    {{ .Data.data.db }}
  {{- end }}`}}
```